# Изменения цвета и интенсивности Emission материала через скрипт

Tags: c#, unity3d, color

У меня есть дочерний объект, в материале которого установлен Emission. 
Нужно постепенное изменение интенсивности и цвета Emission.

Comment: и что дальше было?

Comment: если изменение произошло, но было мгновенным, тогда вам нужны либо корутины либо в апдейте менять значение по чуть-чуть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Важно понимать, что HDR - это все тот же обычный цвет, но без ограничения `[0..1]` для каждого канала. "Интенсивность" HDR - это, по сути, второй множитель из формулы: `HDR_color = RGB_color * intensity_multiplier`. Причем `intensity_multiplier` **должен быть больше или равен нуля** - это очевидно, но все же важно упомянуть.

```
public class MaterialController : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    Color start;
    [SerializeField]
    Color end;

    // Изменяйте эту интенсивность где угодно, хоть в Update, хоть из внешнего скрипта
    public float intensity = 1f;

    Material material;

    public void Start(){
        material = GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().material;
    }

    public void Update(){
        // Устанавливайте цвет так, как вам нужно
        // Данная реализация будет моргать цветом от start до end
        Color currentColor = Color.Lerp(start, end, (Mathf.Sin(Time.time) + 1) / 2);

        // Пользуемся формулой из объяснений выше для контроля интенсивности
        material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", currentColor * intensity);
    }
}
```

Для лучшей производительности стоит кэшировать id переменных материалов:

```
public class MaterialController : MonoBehaviour {
    ...

    Material material;
    int emissionColorId;

    public void Start(){
        ...
        emissionColorId = Shader.PropertyToID("_EmissionColor");
    }

    public void Update(){
        ...
        material.SetColor(emissionColorId, currentColor * intensity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Позвольте.. Где здесь устанавливается Intensity? Мне нужно плавно ее с 10 до 0 убрать....

Comment: @tebenkov2222 а где в вопросе указано, что вам нужно устанавливать `Intensity`? :)

Comment: "постепенное выключение светимости объекта". С цветом то я разобрался.. Но я уже битый час убиваюсь с Intensity.. Нигде нет нормальной информации того, как изменять Intensity. Если вы знаете, то можете подсказать?

Comment: @tebenkov2222 я сейчас дополню ответ, просто на будущее: пишите внятные вопросы. Вы спросили, как установить цвет в шейдере - я ответил, как установить цвет в шейдере. Догадаться, что вы хотите использовать интенсивность, я не могу :)

Comment: @tebenkov2222 добавил информацию об интенсивности

Comment: А как тогда устанавливается intensity? когда я делаю 5 - становится 2,7....

Comment: @tebenkov2222 Я написал, как, от 0 до скольки хотите. "когда я делаю 5 - становится 2,7", становится где? В инспекторе материала? Там есть отрицательные значения, хотя минимальное значение intensity - 0. Если вкратце, шкала в инспекторе преобразует эти значения не так, как вы предполагаете, для полного понимания нужно лезть в исходники. Если вы по моему коду будете устанавливать intensity от 0 до 10 и наоборот - получите верный результат.